# Detox: Multiple matcher count?

Tags: detox

Is it possible to get the count of matches in multiple matches?

My case is: I have a list of ~20 items, they are server-side based, so it can change, and I want to be able to test each of them (they are toggles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible currently, but will be possible in the near future, with the new `getAttributes()` API. This is planned for release soon.

See the documentation [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/DetoxNext/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#getattributes--ios-only)

```js
const multipleMatchedElements = await element(by.text('Multiple')).getAttributes();
jestExpect(multipleMatchedElements.elements.length).toBe(5);
jestExpect(multipleMatchedElements.elements[0].identifier).toBe('FirstElement');
```